# Submit button not hitting isset() call

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP form set like this

```
<?php if (isset($submitted)) {
$output = checkData(); 
if (!is_null($output))
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $output . '"); </script>';
}
else 
{
    createMeeting();
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You meeting has been created. All of the recipients should shortly receive an email"); </script>';
    header('Location: index.php');
}   
} else { ?>
<center>
<form method="POST">
...
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Create Meeting">
</form>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

When I run it through a PHP code checker ([codechecker website](http://phpcodechecker.com)), no errors are returned. However, when I click on the submit button, the isset($submitted) code never seems to be executed (I've tested this by adding some echo statements in that section of the code).

If I click on the submit button, the form is cleared, so something is happening. I've put a number of different actions in, but the code is still not hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `if (isset($submitted))...` should be `if (isset($_POST['submitted']))...`

Comment: Thanks - that got it. Only issue now is the $output = checkData(); is being set, so the header condition is being run, however the JS alerts aren't coming up, so I'm not sure what is going on there!

Comment: That is a different question now from the original one you've posted. I suggest you open a new one for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the form is submitted using:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Or check if an individual element of the form has been submitted checking if the name is in the post array using:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
```